# How can I add mouseover event to a route in a Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a Google maps with several routes painted with DirectionsRenderer. I want change the route style with the mouseover event, but I don't find how, is posible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to attach events directly to the polyline drawn by the `DirectionsRenderer`. To accomplish this you'll instead need to draw your own polyline on top (hence the `zIndex`) and then attach `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to that.

Here's an example of how it's done, assuming you only have one route:

```
var polylineOptions = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

var polylineOptionsMouseOver = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10
});

google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'directions_changed', function(event) {

    var path = dirRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].overview_path;
    var eventLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        visible: true,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        zIndex: 1000
    }); 
    eventLine.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(eventLine, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        dirRenderer.setOptions({
            'polylineOptions':polylineOptionsMouseOver, 
            'preserveViewport': true
        });
        dirRenderer.setMap(map);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(eventLine, 'mouseout', function(event) {
        dirRenderer.setOptions({
            'polylineOptions':polylineOptions,
            'preserveViewport': true
        });
        dirRenderer.setMap(map);
    });

});
```

Since you say you have multiple routes, you may need to loop through the `routes[]` array and do something for each route. Also, I don't think you can style a specific route, so you may need to keep each route in a separate `DirectionsRenderer`.

Comment: Thank you. With this, I get what I want, but I have a problem: With the setMap el map move the focus and zoom, how can i avoid it?

Comment: Oh.. just include 'preserveViewport':true when setting the `dirRenderer` options. I'll edit my original answer.